# Is it possible to transfer an OEM Windows 10 license?

Tags: windows-10, installation, license, license-key

I want to change the drive on my laptop to an SSD. I use Windows 10, and I have two options :

- clone the HDD to an SSD
- install a fresh copy of Windows 10 on the new drive

Since I would like to use the opportunity of the move to freshen up my  5 years old installation, I would like to go the reinstall way.

The first problem is the installation media for Windows 10. It [would seem](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/software-download/windows10ISO) that it is possible to create install media directly from Microsoft.

The second problem is the license: **is there a way to transfer it from my existing installation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to "transfer the license". Licenses are attached to motherboards, not to hard drives, you can just install a fresh copy of Windows on your new drive and use the same OEM license. 
You mention a 5 years old installation, which I can only assume you did the painful windows 7 to Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 upgrade.
In which case I will encourage you to download a fresh ISO from Windows, and do the install either with a USB or disc, then just use your key, should be fine.

Comment: Once you've done the Windows 7 or 8/8.1 to 10 upgrade you don't even need to enter a key to reactivate Windows 10. It will automatically activate again if you re-install, based on the hardware. Changing the hard drive won't interfere with that.